# Python: Error decoding json while loading

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting an error when running this in a python script. Can someone suggest me what do I need to change here with the new implementation?

```
def mything():
    raw_format = 'some dynamic string'
    print(raw_format)
    json_format = json.loads(raw_format, strict= False)
    json_format['color']='blue'
    another_thing = json.dumps(json_format, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

Error:

```
> File "myfile", line 14, in mything
    json_format = json.loads(raw_format, strict= False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 351, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. The error you pasted only show the origin from with the error originated.

Comment: You cut of the most important part of the Traceback.